# Filter Album with empty set of tracks Django-Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(
        Album, related_name='tracks', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True
    )
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

**Now how can i get the collection of `Album` with empty set of tracks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
Album.objects.filter(tracks__isnull=True)
```

Comment: this works too i tried Album.objects.filter(tracks=None)

Answer (score 1):

Just read the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null). You can't save a model with field who haven't value **or** you need to had `null=True` to allow null field save in your database

models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

*Info: if your database is Postgre, it's recommended to initialize field at `null=True`.*

EDIT: thank so much for people who had negative point but never give answer.

To get list of Album with empty tracks. You need to save empty tracks first, related to the album (it's why you need to add `null=True`) and do a query like that :

```
Album.tracks.all()
```

This query take the Album of your choice, and select all tracks who have this album was related name. So the result is a query with the list of tracks who have Album has key.

Comment: maybe you dont get what my question is anyway thanks for the response